# RegEx - Match 2 or more CSS Properties & Capture their values inside of single class

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, less

I have a need where I have several stylesheets; all different that need to get converted over to a few LESS Mixins to assist with browser compatibility.

For instance, the mixin is called ".size()" and it will allow for a width and height to be placed in naturally. The other is ".txt()" and allows much more to be placed.

Example CSS:

```
.window {
    font-style:italic;
    width:100%;
    line-height:2em;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#ccc;
    height:40%;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Written via Mixin:

```
.window { 
    .size(100% 40%); 
    .txt(1.5 b u i lh 2em #ccc); 
    border:1px solid #000; 
}
```

What is needed is the ability to match and capture 2 or more CSS properties within a grouping of { }. I have the following which can match one and have been attempting to modify it to find another. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

RegEx to Match Single Property (not in group of { } ):

```
\s\b(?:width\s*?:\s*([^;>!]*?)(?=[;">}]))
```

Comment: do you want to find all properties or just specific ones? your regex specifically finds 'width'

Comment: Ideally I would like to match width & height and combine their values into a single mixin. I could then extrapolate the RegEx to handle other's like the .txt() mixin. But I need to make sure their all part of a single { } group.

Comment: Example:
    #myId{ width:300px; height:100px; }
    .myClass{ height:500px; width:200px; }
Matched & Replaced String:
    #myId{ .size(300px 100px); }
    .myClass{ .size(200px 500px); }

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the first choice in your case. The nature of the CSS language make use of regex here painful.

Instead, I suggest you to use a CSS parser.

You can check this article for a list of CSS parsers written in Javascript:

- http://codetheory.in/parsing-css-in-javascript/

or simply type `javascript css parser` in your favorite search engine.